# Bash command not working in cygwin cron

Tags: bash, cron, cygwin

I'm running bash scripts without any problem in cygwin (running over XP), but as soon as I try to execute them in cron, they just do nothing.

This is my crontab line:

```
* * * * * bash /cygdrive/d/DESCARGAS/test.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I've also tried with `/bin/sh` and `/bin/bash` instead of the plain `bash` command.

I tested the crontab is running with the typical testing line, so that's not the problem.

It is also strange that the cron.log is empty, and therefore doesn't give me any clue about the solution.

What do you think should I do next?

Comment: Have you tried not redirecting all output away to `/dev/null` and seeing if the cron log says anything at that point? What does `test.sh` do?

Comment: test.sh is just:

#!/bin/bash
echo "prueba" >> ejemplo.txt

Comment: Try using a full path to that output file (cron doesn't necessarily run from where you would expect). What about the cron log after dropping the redirections?

Comment: You were right! It was the full path issue. Thanks a lot Etan!

Comment: @EtanReisner: I suggest you post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a full path to the output file in your script (cron doesn't necessarily run from where you would expect so you may be looking in the wrong place for the output file).

For future reference the **Debugging crontab** section of the [crontab](/questions/tagged/crontab) [info wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info) has suggestions for tips on how to debug cron job problems.

Specifically in this case section six is the key section though the info wiki focuses on the environment of the command and doesn't mention the working directory the issue is, ultimately, the same.

Answer (score -2):

i think you are missing the .exe /bin/bash.exe not bash did you try with .exe

Comment: In Cygwin, you can omit the `.exe` suffix. This provides a better emulation of Unix-like systems, where executable typically don't have extensions.